# Failed to download apple-app-site-association file on iOS13 using Charles Proxy

Tags: ios, charles-proxy, apple-app-site-associate

We usually use the Charles proxy when we develop our apps. The problem is that when we use the Charles proxy to capture HTTP request and Response on iOS13 device, we cannot download the `apple-app-site-association` file, as the title says.
It worked fine until iOS12.
Here is a capture of the request to get the `app-site-association` file when installing the app.

This says

> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

But after that `GET /apple-app-site-association` request does not seem to be executed.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

iOS13

[image]

iOS12
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a lot of research and trial and error, but in the end I could not find the cause. However, I was able to get the `apple-app-site-association` by removing the corresponding domain from the `SSL Proxy Setting` when installing the app.

[image: Charles > Proxy > SSL Proxy Settings]